# Very Sample InAppBrowser not run

Tags: cordova

I have a trouble with using InAppBrowser.

I use Visual Studio 2012, DevExtreme 14.1

I have a sample code like this :

In DxView :

```
<button onclick="callGoogle()">Login</button>
```

In JS file :

```
function callGoogle() {

var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
$(ref).on('loadstart', function (e) { alert('start: ' + e.url); });
}
```

I also try :

```
function callGoogle() {

var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
$(ref).addEventListener('loadstart', function (e) { alert('start: ' + e.url); });
}
```

I don't know why it cannot run the loadstart event.
It can open a new blank window, but it cannot run the loadstart event, the alert is not shown up.

Do i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

you dont use jquery method on javascript variable. code sample from documentation says

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert(event.url); });
```

Comment: Yes, i also changed it to   
  
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank',  'location=yes');

     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {  alert(event.url); });

But no use :(

Comment: what version of phonegap do you use? did you add the inappbrowser plugin to config?

Comment: i use phonegap 3.3, and this is my config.xml after build native package as zip

        <author href="example.com" email="mail@example.com">PhoneGap  User</author>

        <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0"/>

        <access origin="http://google.com"/>
        <access origin="http://apache.org"/>

        <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>

Comment: I think inappbrowser should also be added as feature like this <feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser read doc about it

Comment: Hi Marcin, but for now, i only run my app as debug on Visual Studio, where can i find the config.xml ? Does the InAppBrowser can run on Firefox, Google Chrome or IE ?

Comment: im not sure if it will work as debug on VS (I never used VS). if you created app in console, then you should add the plugin via console and it should be ok.